# Regex Error - (incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to do something which seems like it should be very simple. I'm trying to see if a specific string e.g. 'out of stock' is found within a page's source code. However, I don't care if the string is contained within an html comment or javascript. So prior to doing my search, I'd like to remove both of these elements using regular expressions. This is the code I'm using.

```rb
urls.each do |url|
  response = HTTP.get(url)
     if response.status.success?
        source_code = response.to_s
        # Remove comments
        source_code = source_code.gsub(/<!--(.*?)-->/su, '')
        # Remove scripts
        source_code = source_code.gsub(/<script(.*?)<\/script>/msu, '')

        if source_code.match(/out of stock/i)
           # Flag URL for further processing
        end
     end
  end
end
```

This works for 99% of all the urls I tried it with, but certain urls have become problematic. When I try to use these regular expressions on the source code returned for the url "https://www.sunski.com" I get the following error message:

`Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string))`

The page is definitely UTF-8 encoded, so I don't really understand the error message. A few people on stack overflow recommended using the `# encoding: UTF-8` comment at the top of the file, but this didn't work.

If anyone could help with this it would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should only use `m` modifier with your regex: `/<script(.*?)<\/script>/m`

Comment: "The page is definitely UTF-8 encoded". Good rule for debugging: never assume, always check. Did you check what `source_code.encoding` returns?

Comment: @Casper I guess I have a fundamental misunderstanding how encoding works. I visited the page's source and saw the line `<meta charset="utf-8">` and in the Chrome console called `document.characterSet`. Both seemed to indicate UTF-8 encoding but I see using the method you described that the encoding is not what I expected! Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This actually worked... I'm not quite sure how now that I know the encoding was actually mismatched. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Casper  `source_code` is guaranteed to be a binary string because `Net::HTTP` doesn't care about the encoding of the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Net::HTTP` standard library only returns binary (`ASCII-8BIT`) strings. See the long-standing feature request: [Feature #2567: Net::HTTP does not handle encoding correctly](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2567). So if you want UTF-8 strings you have to manually set their encoding to UTF-8 with [`String#force_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding):

```
source_code.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

If the website's character encoding isn't UTF-8 you have to implement a heuristic based on the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header or `<meta>`'s [`charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) attribute but even then it might not be the correct encoding. You can validate a string's encoding with [`String#valid_encoding?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding-3F) if you need to deal with such cases. Thankfully most websites use UTF-8 nowadays.

Also as @WiktorStribiżew already wrote in the comments, the regexp encoding specifiers `s` (Windows-31J) and `u` (UTF-8) modifiers aren't necessary here and only very rarely are. Especially the latter one since modern Ruby defaults to UTF-8 (or, if sufficient, its subset US-ASCII) anyway. In other programming languages they may have a different meaning, e.g. in Perl `s` means *single line*.